# Node.js streams => Delete contents of folder before transpiling to it

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using Gulp and I would like to delete/"clean" all contents of a directory before writing transpiled source to it.

Is there a way to connect the stream that runs the delete operation to the stream that does the read/transform/write operation?

Right now I have this:

```
function transpileJSX() {

    var d = domain.create();

    d.run(function () {
        gulp.src('./public/static/app/js/views/**/*.js').pipe(react({harmony: true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/static/app/js/jsx')).on('end', function () {
            d.emit('end');
            d.exit();
        });
    });

    return d;


}

function deleteJSX() {
    return gulp.src('./public/static/app/js/jsx/**/*.js')
        .pipe(clean({force: true}));
}


gulp.task('transpile-jsx', function () {
    return transpileJSX().on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});

gulp.task('delete-jsx', function (cb) {
    return deleteJSX();
});
```

the problem is that this doesn't seem to work:

```
deleteJSX().pipe(transpileJSX());
```

the transpileJSX operation seems to start before the deleteJSX operation begins. And that might be expected when it comes to streams. But I think I want to make sure the whole thing works properly by ensuring the entire delete operation completes first?

For example, if I do this:

```
gulp.task('some-task', ['delete-jsx','transpile-jsx'], function (done) {

    someTask(done);

});
```

the gulp logs show that the transpile-jsx task starts before the delete-jsx task ends.

If someone has a pattern to use when it comes to cleaning out a folder before transpiling to it, I'd like to copy it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there already. You just have to rearrange task dependencies, since gulp runs tasks for maximum concurrency:

```
gulp.task('transpile-jsx', ['delete-jsx'], function () {
  //...
});

gulp.task('some-task', ['transpile-jsx'], function () {
  //...
});
```

This will be easier once Gulp 4 hits. There you will be able to write stuff like:

```
gulp.task('some-task', gulp.series('delete-jsx', 'transpile-jsx', function () {
  //...
}));
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense! do you know when gulp 4 will be released?

Comment: There's no set [due date](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/milestones) yet, because of [some outstanding breaking changes](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1486), but you can [install the current development version](http://blog.reactandbethankful.com/posts/2015/05/01/how-to-install-gulp-4/) if you wanna try it. I've been playing with it and haven't run into any problems yet, but YMMV.